# Differing behavior with Python script on RHEL and Debian, nearly identical python versions

Tags: python, debian, rhel

I rarely post questions to a forum, but this one has me stumped. I'm very curious as to what's causing this (a solution would also be nice, but mostly, I'd like to know why I'm having this issue):

I recently wrote a python script for wrapping the invocation of remote commands which are started by a PBS job:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright (c) 2009 Maciej Brodowicz
# Copyright (c) 2011 Bryce Lelbach
#
# Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
# file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)

from datetime import datetime

from string import letters, digits

from types import StringType

from optparse import OptionParser

from threading import Thread

# subprocess instantiation wrapper. Unfortunately older Python still lurks on
# some machines.
try:
  from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT, PIPE
  from types import StringType

  class process:
    _proc = None
    _exec = None

    def __init__(self, cmd):
      self._proc = Popen(cmd, stderr = STDOUT, stdout = PIPE,
        shell = (False, True)[type(cmd) == StringType])

    def poll(self):
      return self._proc.poll()

    def pid(self):
      return self._proc.pid

    def _call(self):
      # annoyingly, KeyboardInterrupts are transported to threads, while most
      # other Exceptions aren't in python
      try:
        self._proc.wait()
      except Exception, err:
        self._exec = err

    def wait(self, timeout=None):
      if timeout is not None:
        thread = Thread(target=self._call)
        thread.start()

        # wait for the thread and invoked process to finish
        thread.join(timeout)

        # be forceful
        if thread.is_alive():
          self._proc.terminate()
          thread.join()

          # if an exception happened, re-raise it here in the master thread 
          if self._exec is not None:
            raise self._exec

          return (True, self._proc.returncode)

        if self._exec is not None:
          raise self._exec

        return (False, self._proc.returncode)

      else:
        return (False, self._proc.wait())

    def read(self):
      return self._proc.stdout.read()

except ImportError, err:
  # no "subprocess"; use older popen module
  from popen2 import Popen4
  from signal import SIGKILL
  from os import kill, waitpid, WNOHANG

  class process:
    _proc = None

    def __init__(self, cmd):
      self._proc = Popen4(cmd)

    def poll(self):
      return self._proc.poll()

    def pid(self):
      return self._proc.pid

    def _call(self):
      # annoyingly, KeyboardInterrupts are transported to threads, while most
      # other Exceptions aren't in python
      try:
        self._proc.wait()
      except Exception, err:
        self._exec = err

    def wait(self, timeout=None):
      if timeout is not None:
        thread = Thread(target=self._call)
        thread.start()

        # wait for the thread and invoked process to finish
        thread.join(timeout)

        # be forceful
        if thread.is_alive():
          kill(self._proc.pid, SIGKILL)
          waitpid(-1, WNOHANG)
          thread.join()

          # if an exception happened, re-raise it here in the master thread 
          if self._exec is not None:
            raise self._exec

          return (True, self._proc.wait())

        if self._exec is not None:
          raise self._exec

        return (False, self._proc.wait())

      else:
        return (False, self._proc.wait())

    def read(self):
      return self._proc.fromchild.read()

def run(cmd, timeout=3600):
  start = datetime.now() 
  proc = process(cmd)
  (timed_out, returncode) = proc.wait(timeout)
  now = datetime.now()

  output = ''

  while True:
    s = proc.read()

    if s:
      output += s
    else:
      break

  return (returncode, output, timed_out)

def rstrip_last(s, chars):
  if s[-1] in chars:
    return s[:-1]
  else:
    return s

# {{{ main
usage = "usage: %prog [options]" 

parser = OptionParser(usage=usage)

parser.add_option("--timeout",
                  action="store", type="int",
                  dest="timeout", default=3600,
                  help="Program timeout (seconds)")

parser.add_option("--program",
                  action="store", type="string",
                  dest="program",
                  help="Program to invoke") 

(options, cmd) = parser.parse_args()

if None == options.program:
  print "No program specified"
  exit(1)

(returncode, output, timed_out) = run(options.program, options.timeout)

if not 0 == len(output):
  print rstrip_last(output, '\n')

if timed_out:
  print "Program timed out"

exit(returncode)
# }}}
```

Another python script puts together the command line arguments based on available resources as reported by PBS, similar to mpirun. I use python-paramiko for starting the remote commands over SSH. Initially I just executed the commands directly, but I failed to receive the correct exit codes when one of the remotely run processes exited with a signal (e.g. SIGSEGV). Thus, the need for the above script.

When running this script on my development cluster at work, I noticed that this script is subtly failing to work on my 4-core Debian GNU/Linux nodes, yet it does work on my 48-core RHEL/Linux nodes:

On the Debian nodes:

```
wash@hermione0:~/sandbox$ python --version
Python 2.6.7
wash@hermione0:~/sandbox$ uname -a
Linux hermione0 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 12 03:40:32 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
wash@hermione0:~/sandbox$ time ./hpx_invoke.py --program='sleep 30' --timeout=5
Program timed out

real 0m30.025s
user 0m0.016s
sys  0m0.012s
wash@hermione0:~/sandbox$
```

On the RHEL nodes:

```
[22:08:23]:wash@vega:/home/wash/sandbox$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
[22:09:28]:wash@vega:/home/wash/sandbox$ uname -a
Linux vega 2.6.32-131.4.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 10 10:54:26 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[22:09:30]:wash@vega:/home/wash/sandbox$ time ./hpx_invoke.py --program='sleep 30' --timeout=5
Program timed out

real 0m5.053s
user 0m0.040s
sys  0m0.020s
[22:09:41]:wash@vega:/home/wash/sandbox$
```

What could be causing this?

P.S. I'm the sysadmin on these boxes.

Comment: Maybe it's just kind of late, but what exactly is failing on the Debian nodes that is succeeding on the RHEL nodes?  I understand the RHEL version "times out" "faster," but what exactly is the expected behavior?

Comment: It's not late. If the invoked program runs for three hours on Debian with a timeout of 40 seconds, it only gets killed after it exits. On RHEL, it times out after the specified timeout.

Comment: Too late to be looking at that much code. My brain is all fried from looking at code all day long, can't you just paste a suspect line and then I'll say "aha, you didn't close a parenthesis" and then you smack yourself on the head and I grin a smug grin because I know that's probably the only question I could possibly answer right now.

Comment: Shove your code through a profiler.

Comment: You have essentially 2 versions. Print which branch (subprocess or not) is used in either case. This will halve the search space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be invoking subprocesses as shell (both machines have the subprocess package). On the RHEL nodes, when /bin/sh is killed, the program invoked is also killed. On the Debian nodes, only the /bin/sh process is killed, and the program that it's invoked remains alive.

I fixed this by changing the script to no longer use shell=True.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that a difference in the packages available is causing a different branch of your "subprocess instantiation wrapper" to be used on either machine. In one branch, you'd be using SIGTERM (the `terminate()` call) and in the other, SIGKILL.

Having said that, `sleep` seems to end prematurely given either signal. There are probably other differences, but it's hard to tell. You'd be best off putting in some debugging code to see what happens on what machine.